# JQuery - JNotify - Click-function issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using JNotify-plugin to display notifications on my site. I works well, but I need to use a click-function to trigger some events.

Basiclly what happens is:

When I get a new chat-message my JNotify-function triggers and a notification-div shows up. Then when I click that div, I want to trigger my other fuction(the #showNewMsg-click-function). But it won't work. If I use any other div to trigger the #showNewMsg-click-function everything works fine. But not when clicking the JNotify rendered div. So how can a make this work?

Here is my try...

JNotify-fuction:

```
var newMessage;
        $(function () {
            newMessage = function () {
                jSuccess(
                    "<div id='showNewMsg'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-envelope'></i>" + ' New chat msg! Click to read!' + '</div>',
                    {
                        autoHide: false,
                        HideTimeEffect: 500,
                        LongTrip: 20,
                        ColorOverlay: '#000',
                        HorizontalPosition: "center",
                        VerticalPosition: "bottom",
                        ShowOverlay: false,
                        OpacityOverlay: 0.5,
                        MinWidth: 350
                    });
            }
            newMessage();
        });
```

Click-funtion to trigger some other click events:

```
$("#showNewMsg").click(function () {

        $("#chat-toggle").click();

        $('a[href="#room1"]').click();
    });
```

[JNotify GitHub](https://github.com/alpixel/jNotify)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers my own question, in case somone else is wondering.

Found the answer, by reading the JNotify-documentation a little bit closer.

By adding the onClosed-part, instead of trying to do a separate function with click-events, everything works perfect now.

onClosed fires of when the notification div is closed.

```
var newMessage;
        $(function () {
            newMessage = function () {
                jSuccess(
                    "<div id='showNewMsg'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-envelope'></i>" + ' New chat msg! Click to read!' + '</div>',
                    {
                        autoHide: false,
                        HideTimeEffect: 500,
                        LongTrip: 20,
                        ColorOverlay: '#000',
                        HorizontalPosition: "center",
                        VerticalPosition: "bottom",
                        ShowOverlay: false,
                        OpacityOverlay: 0.5,
                        MinWidth: 350,
                        //THIS PART BELOW
                        onClosed: function () {
                            $("#chat-toggle").click();

                            $('a[href="#room1"]').click();
                        },
                    });
            }
            newMessage();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the notification DIV is being inserted into the DOM dynamically, it never gets bound to that click you set up. Try binding the click in the onCompleted function of jNotify. This function fires after the element is inserted, so you should be able to operate on it.

```
jSuccess(
  "<div id='showNewMsg'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-envelope'></i>" + ' New chat msg! Click to read!' + '</div>',
  {
    autoHide: false,
    HideTimeEffect: 500,
    LongTrip: 20,
    ColorOverlay: '#000',
    HorizontalPosition: "center",
    VerticalPosition: "bottom",
    ShowOverlay: false,
    OpacityOverlay: 0.5,
    MinWidth: 350,
    onCompleted : function() {
      $("#showNewMsg").click(function () {
        alert('You clicked on the notification!');
      });
    }
  }
);
```

[jsFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/94vu6LxL/)